# Why is Flask not loading images the second time I render a template?

Tags: html, flask

I have made a ML model which I am deploying in a website using Flask. This is the code for it:

**main.py**

```
#imports

app = Flask(__name__)

def check(url):
    #function to check whether the URL entered by user is Phishing or not and return the result

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html") #renders homepage template

@app.route('/phish/<url>')
def phish(url):
    for i in range(0,len(url)):
        if url[i]=="$":
            url = url[:i]+"/"+url[i+1:] #changing url back to original
    return render_template("phish.html", url=url)

@app.route('/safe/<url>')
def safe(url):
    for i in range(0,len(url)):
        if url[i]=="$":
            url = url[:i]+"/"+url[i+1:] #changing url back to original
    return render_template("safe.html", url=url)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    url = request.form['url']
    result = check(url)
    for i in range(0,len(url)):
        if url[i]=="/":
            url = url[:i]+"$"+url[i+1:] #changing "//" to "$$"
    if result==1 :
        return redirect(url_for("phish", url=url))
    else :
        return redirect(url_for("safe", url=url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <!-- bunch of meta tags -->
    <title>PhishLearn</title>

    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- for loading 
    css -->

  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- body code -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code for **phish.html** and **safe.html** is also exactly same except for some changes in the body part.

Now when I initially run my main.py file the home page is loaded perfectly. But when I input a URL and click submit the page that is then rendered according to the result (phish or safe) does not display any image. Here are the screenshots of the pages:

**Homepage**
[image: Homepage]

**Result Page**
[image: phish]

As you can see when safe.html is rendered it does not shows any images. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's inspector to see what is happening? E.g. the URLs attempted for the broken images.

Comment: How I do check that? I mean what do I look for in Inspector window?

Comment: The requests in the network tab. They'd likely be red.

Comment: Yes. Why is it so?

Comment: What are the URLs? I'd imagine they're wrong.

Comment: In my home page it says (index) under initiator column for all images but in the results page it shows red URLs why is it so? What's happening here?

Comment: What is the actual URL that's erroring out, not the initiator? Is it maybe something like `/phish/static/...` instead of `/static/`?

Comment: It just says text/html for all images

Comment: That's the content type column, not the URL column.

Comment: There's no URL column.

Comment: Right-click the table headers and make sure either Path or Url is checked, then.

Comment: Yes. Its adding phish in the path before static.

Comment: What do I do? Should I make a seperate folder for phish and safe pages with the same name and keep all my images there?

Comment: You'll need to figure out why Flask is not using an absolute path for url_for("static").

Comment: Im also making some changes to the URL submitted by user. Since I need to pass its value to the phish/safe page im doing it through their route. But since I cannot keep a full URL in the path im changing the "//" to "$$" (I have added the code for that in my question). Is it possible that this might be causing the problem?

Comment: That won't be the issue. Please show how you're referring to those images. Nothing in the code you've posted refers to any image.

Comment: I just use the src attribute of img tag to specify the path of file. Since all my html resources (css, js, images, etc.) are inside the static folder so I write src = "static/img/image-name.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

> I just use the src attribute of img tag to specify the path of file. Since all my html resources (css, js, images, etc.) are inside the static folder so I write src = "static/img/image-name.jpg"

That's your problem (as I kind of guessed).

When the URL in your browser is `/phish/foople.blarp.quux`, then `static/img/image-name.jpg` relative to that path is `/phish/foople.blarp.quux/static/img/image-name.jpg` which obviously 404s.

You *need to*

- use the `{% url_for("static", filename=...) %}` form so Flask will deal with forming the correct static URL,
- or alternately but less preferably (since changing the static files' root path will then require you to edit every template you have) use an absolute path `/static/img/image-name.jpg`.
- or if you feel like using esoteric and often-forgot-about HTML features, set `<base>` and never worry about relative paths, but really please don't do that.

Comment: Okay. So just to be sure will my url_for form look like, `src = {{ url_for('static', filename= 'img/image-name.jpg)  }}` right?

Comment: e.g. `<img src="{{url_for('static', filename= 'img/image-name.jpg')}}">`, yes.